# viewstate on asp.net 3.?

Tags: asp.net

Can i disable viewstate on asp.net 3.5 applicatoin because i don't know programming on asp.net mvc?

Comment: Why do you want to disable viewstate in a asp.net application which isn't mvc? You can disable viewstate on specific controls in your application, but viewstate can be useful.

Comment: This particular question, I'm sorry if it sounds rude, but... "If you don't know, you shouldn't be doing it". By this, I mean you don't know or understand what the viewstate is, so you shouldn't be touching it, until you know.

Answer (score 3):

try following code

```
private void Page_Init(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.EnableViewState = false;
}
```

or this

```
<%@ Page EnableViewState="False" ... %>
```

or in web.config

```
<system.web>
  <pages enableViewState="false"/>   
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be a few ways to accomplish this:

1. Set [EnableViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableviewstate.aspx) to false.  (For the page or per-control.)
2. Override [viewstate-related methods](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=513355) on the page.
3. Disable it on a per-folder basis in [Web.config](http://www.codedigest.com/CodeDigest/157-Disable-ViewState-for-a-Set-of-ASP-Net-Pages-in-a-Folder.aspx).

There are likely more approaches to this, Google is your friend.  I don't have any direct experience with doing this, but it's been tried a lot for mobile applications and other bandwidth-critical services.

The bigger question, however, is why you want to do this?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: you can also disable it on application basis, using that web.config method but omitting the folder-node

Answer (score 0):

This is not so simple job to create applications with ASP.NET WebForms without using ViewStates. Yes disabling the ViewSates is very easy; just set EnableViewState to "False" or ... But the more important problem is that the ViewState is not bad thing at all! Sometimes you will not be able to do some works in ASP.NET WebForms without using ViewStates.

The MVC has more benefits than just being ViewState-free! Although ASP.NET is more component-oriented than MVC, but MVC is another thing and has its own advantages and disadvantages.

Don't worry just about ViewState while thinking about "MVC" vs "ASP.NET WebForms".